# how to make useAppSelector wait for data from Get request (instead of showing initial data)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have this reducer

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const projectSlice = createSlice({
name: "project-redux",
initialState: {
    name: "",
},
reducers: {
    get_project: (state, action) => {
    axios
        .get("http://localhost:5000/api/project/" + action.payload)
        .then((res) => {
        state = res.data; //which contains the name
    
        });
    },
},
});

export const { get_project } = projectSlice.actions;

export default projectSlice.reducer;
```

and want to access the "name" with useAppSelector

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

const {name}=useAppSelector(state=>state.projs) //projs is the name of projectsReducer in the store
console.log(name) // only give initial state
```

How do I get the 'name' value after the get request is fulfilled?

### Solution:

```
    export const fetchProject = createAsyncThunk(
    "fetchProject",
    async (id) => {
        const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/project/" + id);

        return res.data.title;
    }
    );
  reducers: {//other reducers if ther is}
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(fetchProject.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.title = action.payload;
        });
    },
```

then:

```
const name = useAppSelector((state) => state.projs.title);
console.log("selecttitle", name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the side effect(I/O operations) code inside reducer functions. The redux reducer function should be pure. You should use [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) to fetch data.

After your dispatch the async thunk, you should mutate the state with the fetched data inside `extraReducers` field of `createSlice`. After mutating the state, the component will re-render, then the `useAppSelector` will be called. You will read the state fetched from the remote server from the redux store.

E.g.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

import { useEffect } from 'react';

export const fetchProject = createAsyncThunk('fetchProject', (id) => {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/project/' + id).then((res) => res.data);
});

export const projectSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'project-redux',
  initialState: {
    name: '',
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchProject.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.name = action.payload;
    });
  },
});

export default projectSlice.reducer;

// Component

import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
function Test() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { name } = useSelector((state) => state.projs);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProject('1'));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <div>{name}</div>;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, it is just way too confusing for me, i couldn't get it to work, but thanks

Comment: @tahamaatof Added code, it doesn't actually run, but in my experience, that's fine, you need to change the state depending on what data is returned

Comment: thank you once more, i made it work thanks to your help